# ExpressJS application doesn't load CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

My ExpressJS web app only loads HTML file but CSS rules are not applied. I linked the HTML file with the CSS file and also added `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css'))` in **app.js**.

This is my project tree:

```
app.js
/views
- index.html
/css
- style.css
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />` to your HTML template and make sure you `use` the static directory: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')))` in _app.js_

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add [`app.use()`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application). All you are doing now is

```js
express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css'))
```

What you should do is

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')))
```

Also make sure you are referencing the stylesheet in your HTML!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

Comment: Full code? What's path?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the  tag in the HTML file. I had `src='./css/style.css'` but using `src='/style.css'` fixed it.